# How to randomly choose one of several strings?

Tags: delphi, random

I have this code:

```
letsdoit(something,'abcd');
letsdoit(something,'asdfasdf');
letsdoit(something,'gagaga');
```

I want it to be, if possible, just one simple line with the logic like:

```
(letsdoit(something,'abcd')) OR (letsdoit(something,'asdfasdf')) OR (letsdoit(something,'gagaga'));
```

so it has 33% chance to choose either of the three. Or:

```
(letsdoit(something,'abcd')) OR (letsdoit(something,'asdfasdf'))
```

so it has 50% chance to choose the left or 50% chance for the right thing.

My questions are:

1. How to randomize between the three and only do one thing.
2. How to randomize between two things and only do one.

Comment: Call Random(3) and the job is done

Comment: @DavidHeffernan what is the (3) in your example?

Comment: It's the number of choices. I take it you read the documentation for Random?

Comment: thanks i have solved it like this now `var
randomer: integer;



randomer := Random(3);
if randomer = 0 then
begin
letsdoit(something,'abcd');
end;
if randomer = 1 then
begin
letsdoit(something,'asdfasdf');
end;
if randomer = 2 then
begin
letsdoit(something,'gagaga');
end;`

Comment: do not forget to call `Randomize()` at the start of your application...

Comment: 1) Rather use a case statement instead of if-then, or 2) put your strings in a constant array: `const mystrings: array[0..2] of string = ('abcd', 'asdfasdf', 'gagaga');` and then, in your code, choose: `randomer := random(3); str := mystrings[randomer]; letsdoit(str);`, or shorter: `letsdoit(mystrings[random(3)]);`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function RandomChooseString(const A: array of string): string; 
begin
   Result := A[Random(Length(A))]
end;

letsdoit(something, RandomChooseString(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']));
```

Comment: i have a question, you used the "letsdoit" but where is the "something"? And I get an error: Error: Incompatible types: 'Integer' and 'String'

Comment: Just add this parameter of your `letsdoit`.  I've shown a method to choose random string. How to use it - your task.

Comment: Do you realize that `RandomChooseString` does?

Comment: I have to think about it now, I hope i will understand soon

Comment: I don't understand all the `(const A: array of string): string; ` at the top and get some "Incompatible types: 'Integer' and 'String'" error, but it's probably a good answer. i'm just too stupid to understand my mistake

Comment: @Fakir Handez Have you seen my corrected answer with `letsdoit(something,RandomChooseString...` ?

Comment: i don't understand it at all i don't even know what an array or const is. I also don't know how to modify your letsdoit so it also has the something in it and where to put the two things i originally had in my brackets(...). That confuses me the most. And the integer and string error, although I know there is something like StrToInt or IntToStr. So I have lots of learning to do to learn about these simple things

Comment: If you can call `letsdoit(something,'abcd');` then you should be able to call the last line of my answer.

Comment: Ohhhhh.... Thank you very much for stating this so clear. Without it I would have given up for now. It works perfectly. I must have made some error earlier. Thanks again

Comment: I did not even use your corrected version, but    `Result := A[Random(High(A) + 1)]`. And it works. Should I use `Result := A[Random(Length(A))]` instead? What's the difference?

Comment: I missed one closing parenthesis in my answer (Now David corrected it).  `High(A) + 1` is equal to `Length(A)`

Comment: "I don't understand ...". For that, to learn more about the language, you should read the Delphi Language Guide (or Object Pascal Language Guide) that comes with the provided help. You can also read my article: [Open array parameters and array of const](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html).